# Linux continuous file sync?

Tags: linux, rsync

I'm looking for something that probably already exists, but I can't find it.

I have a large file (300G) on tmpfs that is being continuously updated by a process, I want something that will make a copy of the file on a remote server, and keep it in sync; every update to the file on the local server, is sent to the remote server and applied to the file.

I am aware of rsync, but that isn't exactly what I want, as you run rsync once on a static file, it works out and sends the delta, and once it has synced the file it stops.

It's like I need something that hooks into the file system itself to capture and transmit the updates as they are written. The file changes continuously but not all that much, maybe a few MB a minute, so I feel like it should be possible. Is there such a thing, or maybe what I'm trying to do is stupid idk. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: You could use [Distributed Replicated Block Device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_Replicated_Block_Device).

Comment: Btw.: Questions seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more are off-topic. See: [Where can I ask questions that don't fit or are off-topic for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254567/3776858)

Answer (score 1):

You can use lsync, it's very easy to use and is uses rsync on the backed.
If you are using Ubuntu:

```
apt-get -y install lsyncd
```